# How to merge pandas columns in a comma separated way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below

| Id | Other columns | Param1 | Param2 | Param3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 29 |  |  |
| -- |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | 29 | 35 |  |
| 3 |  | 29 |  | 74 |
| 4 |  |  | 11 | 34 |

I want to merge the last three columns using comma as a separator to make the dataframe look like below

| Id | Other columns | Params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Param1=29 |
| -- |  |  |
| 2 |  | Param1=29,Param2=35 |
| 3 |  | Param1=29,Param3=74 |
| 4 |  | Param2=11,Param3=34 |

How do I achieve this using the `merge` function of the pandas dataframe?

### Edit1

I used `Param1`, `Param2` and `Param3` as examples. The actual column names different e.g. `Period`, `Length` etc. Therefore any solution that relies on finding columns using Regex or like operator will not work.

I am able to create another hardcoded dataframe that holds the names of the parameters if that can be of any use

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex first, reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), remove possible missing values, join by `=` and then by `,` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(regex=r'^Param\d').melt(ignore_index=False).dropna(subset=['value'])

#alternative
#df1 = df[['Param1','Param2','Param3']].melt(ignore_index=False).dropna(subset=['value'])
```

---

```
df['Params'] = ((df1['variable'] + '=' + df1['value'].astype(int).astype(str))
                      .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

Or use list comprehension with filter out `NaN`s values:

```
cols = ['Param1','Param2','Param3']

df['Params'] = {k: ','.join(f'{k1}={int(v1)}' for k1, v1 in v.items() if pd.notna(v1))
                   for k, v in df[cols].T.to_dict().items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

```py
def make_params(row):
    # if empty values are '' strings:
    # row = row.replace('', np.nan)
    mask = ~row.isna()
    return ",".join(f"{i}={v}" for i, v in zip(row.index[mask], row[mask]))


last_3_column_names = df.iloc[:, -3:].columns
df["Params"] = df[last_3_column_names].apply(make_params, axis=1)
df = df.drop(last_3_column_names, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Id  Other columns               Params
0   1            NaN            Param1=29
1  --            NaN                     
2   2            NaN  Param1=29,Param2=35
3   3            NaN  Param1=29,Param3=74
4   4            NaN  Param2=11,Param3=34
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.agg.html):

```
cols = df.filter(like="Param").columns
# cols = df.set_index(["Id", ...]).columns

out = (
    df.assign(Params= df[cols].stack().reset_index(-1)
     .astype(str).agg("=".join, axis=1)
     .groupby(level=0).agg(",".join)
             ).drop(cols, axis=1)
 )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    Id Other columns                   Params
0 1.00          None              Param1=29.0
1  NaN          None                      NaN
2 2.00          None  Param1=29.0,Param2=35.0
3 3.00          None  Param1=29.0,Param3=74.0
4 4.00          None  Param2=11.0,Param3=34.0
```